# PowerShell Exporting

Tags: powershell

Can someone point me in the right direction? Basically, I would like to export the results of my testpath to a csv. Below is what I am working with. I have read a couple Microsoft documents but they only seem to confuse me even more. Any feedback is appreciated.

```
$ComputerList = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).name 
$ComputerList
write-host "`n"
Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList)
{

$userfolders = get-childitem "\\$Computer\C$\users\"
foreach ($user in $userfolders) {
$ErrorActionPreference= 'silentlycontinue'
    $path = $user.fullname
    write-host $path 
    $t = test-path -Path "$path\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
    IF ($t -eq 'True') {write-host "Has it" -ForegroundColor yellow} ELSE {write-host "no"} 
     write-host "`n" 
}

$Output =New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{


} | Select-Object 

}
$Output | C:\Users\"user"\Chrome.csv

write-output "Script finished. Please check output files"
```

Comment: You are way over engineering this effort. Don't use Write-Host if you are trying to send data to a file, or down the pipeline. Depending on what Powershell version you are using, Write-Host will clear the buffer, and thus nothing to send. Use Write-Output, but that does not do color and since you can't send color to a file, it's moot anyway. In a loop,s you should be using he output case in the loop, not after it is done, unless you are capturing it in a variable to output separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want a record per user per computer, there's two things you want to change structurally:

- Create new objects in the *inner* `foreach` loop
- Assign *all* the objects created to `$Output`:

```bsh
$ComputerList = (Get-ADComputer -Filter *).name 
$ComputerList
write-host "`n"
$Output = Foreach ($Computer in $ComputerList) {

    $userfolders = get-childitem "\\$Computer\C$\users\"
    foreach ($user in $userfolders) {
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'
        $path = $user.fullname
        write-host $path 
        $t = test-path -Path "$path\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default"
        IF ($t -eq 'True') {write-host "Has it" -ForegroundColor yellow} ELSE {write-host "no"} 
        write-host "`n" 
        New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
            # We still need a bit of magic here
        }
    }

}
$Output | C:\Users\"user"\Chrome.csv

write-output "Script finished. Please check output files"
```

Now we just need to decide on what properties to add to our output objects:

```
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
    # We definitely want to know which computer and user profile the results are for!
    ComputerName = $Computer
    ProfileName  = $user.Name

    # And finally we want the results of `Test-Path`
    Result       = $t
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another option. Though nowhere near as elegant as what Matthias gave you. ***;-}***

It's just a refactor, to narrow down your code and pass everything directly and output by default, without the need for all the, Write-* stuff and the like. PowerShell just grants a number of ways to accomplish a use case.

```
Clear-Host
$null   = New-Item -Path 'C:\Temp\Chrome.csv' -Force
$Status = $null

$env:COMPUTERNAME,'Localhost', '127.0.0.1' | 
Foreach {
    Get-ChildItem "\\$PSItem\C$\users\" | 
    foreach {
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'

        # Use variable squeezing to assign and output to the screen
        ($path = $PSItem.fullname)

        If (test-path -Path "$path\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default") {$Status = 'Has it'} 
        Else {$Status = 'no'} 
    }

    [PSCustomObject] @{
        ComputerName = $PSItem
        Status       = $Status
    } | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Chrome.csv' -Append
}

'Script finished. Please check output files'

# Results on screen
<#
\\104DB2FE-76B8-4\C$\users\ContainerAdministrator
\\104DB2FE-76B8-4\C$\users\ContainerUser
\\104DB2FE-76B8-4\C$\users\Public
\\104DB2FE-76B8-4\C$\users\WDAGUtilityAccount
\\Localhost\C$\users\ContainerAdministrator
\\Localhost\C$\users\ContainerUser
\\Localhost\C$\users\Public
\\Localhost\C$\users\WDAGUtilityAccount
\\127.0.0.1\C$\users\ContainerAdministrator
\\127.0.0.1\C$\users\ContainerUser
\\127.0.0.1\C$\users\Public
\\127.0.0.1\C$\users\WDAGUtilityAccount
Script finished. Please check output files

#>

Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Chrome.csv'
# Results
<#
104DB2FE-76B8-4 no    
Localhost       no    
127.0.0.1       no 
#>

Clear-Host
$null = New-Item -Path 'C:\Temp\Chrome.csv' -Force
$Status = $null

$env:COMPUTERNAME,'Localhost', '127.0.0.1' | 
Foreach {
    Get-ChildItem "\\$PSItem\C$\users\" | 
    foreach {
        $ErrorActionPreference = 'silentlycontinue'

        # Use variable squeezing to assign and output to the screen
        ($path = $PSItem.fullname)

        If (test-path -Path "$path\AppData\Local\MicrosoftEdge") {$Status = 'Has it'} 
        Else {$Status = 'no'} 
    }

    [PSCustomObject] @{
        ComputerName = $PSItem
        Status       = $Status
    } | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Chrome.csv' -Append
}

'Script finished. Please check output files'
# Results
<#
\\104DB2FE-76B8-4\C$\users\ContainerAdministrator
\\104DB2FE-76B8-4\C$\users\ContainerUser
\\104DB2FE-76B8-4\C$\users\Public
\\104DB2FE-76B8-4\C$\users\WDAGUtilityAccount
\\Localhost\C$\users\ContainerAdministrator
\\Localhost\C$\users\ContainerUser
\\Localhost\C$\users\Public
\\Localhost\C$\users\WDAGUtilityAccount
\\127.0.0.1\C$\users\ContainerAdministrator
\\127.0.0.1\C$\users\ContainerUser
\\127.0.0.1\C$\users\Public
\\127.0.0.1\C$\users\WDAGUtilityAccount
Script finished. Please check output files
#>

Import-Csv -Path 'C:\Temp\Chrome.csv'
# Results
<#
ComputerName    Status
------------    ------
104DB2FE-76B8-4 Has it
Localhost       Has it
127.0.0.1       Has it
#>
```

Comment: All answers are appreciated! Thank you!